# buildin itertools.cycle function don’t return next element in While True cycle

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, python-itertools, cycle

I have a function which accepts a dictionary value or a str, create a deque and sort it by index of a that value, than return a cycle object.
Than another function which accepts dict and transfers it in first function object, than in while True loop create another dict which have a “Position” key and value must be a next element in created cycle object, and return that dict but every time in value must be a next element cycle object.

Initial dict
`data = {'position': 'D'}`

First fuction which create and return a cycle() object.

```py
def cycle_(deq_):
    deq = collections.deque(['D', 'E', 'L'])
    idx = deq.index(deq_)
    deq.rotate(-idx)
    cycle = itertools.cycle(deq)
    return cycle
```

Second function which create final dict which must be modified every time and return it.

```
def modification(data):
    dump = cycle_deq(data['position'])
    
    while True:
        data_2 = {
            'position': next(dump)
        }
        return data_2
```

Comment: Please give some example data - input and expected output.

Comment: exemple in first  iteration second function returns a dict_2 -> {‘position’ : ‘D’}, than in second iteration its return a next element exemple  {‘position’ : ‘E’} ect…. and then repeat that operation while not stoped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `modification` function should use `yield` instead of `return`.   In its current form, the while-loop can only run once, then the function terminates with the `return`.